# How to achieve a facet specific ordering of axis entries in ggplot geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I consider the following type of `geom_point` plot. I need to achieve for each vertical facet `s` an ordering of entries on `m` according to their size `v`. The desired order in the plot below is for `s1` A, C, B, D, and for `s2` B, A, C (or B, C, A). The difficulty is that, while I can specify a general order by rearranging the levels of factor `m`, I do not know how to change this order for each facet.

```
set.seed(1)
m1 = c('A','B','C','D')
m2 = c('A','B','C')
s = c(rep('s1',4),rep('s2',3))
d = data.frame(m = factor(c(m1,m2)), s=factor(s), v=sample(1:10, replace=T,7))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=m, y=v)) + geom_point(size=2) + coord_flip() + 
  facet_grid( s~. , scales='free', space='free')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to indeed use factor levels as you described, but use a prefix that seperates the levels for the different facets. Later, you can then use the `labels` argument of the scale to remove the prefix. Example below:

```r
set.seed(1)
m1 = c('1A','1B','1C','1D')
m2 = c('2A','2B','2C')
s = c(rep('s1',4),rep('s2',3))
d = data.frame(m = c(m1,m2), 
               s=factor(s), 
               v=sample(1:10, replace=T,7),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d$m <- factor(d$m, levels = c("1A", "1C", "1B", "1D", "2B", "2A", "2C"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=m, y=v)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_grid( s~. , scales='free', space='free') +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = function(x){substr(x, 2, nchar(x))}
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer seems to change labels but loses the assignment of the correct values.

Comment: I found the last line helpful with the Allan Cameron solution to tidy up the concatenated labels

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to teunbrand's answer, except it uses `forcats` to automatically assign the correct ordering (lowest to highest) within each facet, without needing to specify this in advance:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

d %>% mutate(plot_fct = forcats::fct_cross(s,  m)) %>%
      mutate(plot_fct = forcats::fct_reorder(plot_fct, -v)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=plot_fct, y=v)) + geom_point(size=2) + 
        facet_grid( s~. , scales='free', space='free') +
        scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) substr(x, 4, 5)) +
        coord_flip() + labs(x = "m")
```

[image]